# Output is being displayed twice

Tags: php, sql-server

I have connected to my MS SQL Server 2008 R2 using PHP. Everything works fine except for the fact that the output is being displayed twice.

Below is the PHP code used to make a connection. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost\FAIZ2";
$username = "sa";
$password = "11235813";
$database = "Test";
$connectioninfo = array("UID"=>$username,"PWD"=>$password,"Database"=>$database);
$link = sqlsrv_connect($hostname,$connectioninfo) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM StudentData";
$result = sqlsrv_query($link,$sql) or die("Unable to select: ".sqlsrv_errors());
print "<table>\n";
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
print "<tr>\n";
foreach($row as $field) {
    print "<td>$field</td>\n";
}
print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
sqlsrv_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: What specifically is being printed twice?

Comment: For example, if there are three columns in my database, say id, FName, LName, containing values{1,abc,def}, values{2,ghi,jkl} and {3,mno,pqr}, the output is like this =>
[{"0":1,"id":1,"1":"abc","Fname":"abc","2":"def","Lname":"def"},{"0":2,"id":2,"1":"ghi","Fname":"ghi","2":"jkl","Lname":"jkl"},{"0":3,"id":3,"1":"mno","Fname":"mno","2":"pqr","Lname":"pqr"},{"0":3,"id":3,"1":"mno","Fname":"mno","2":"pqr","Lname":"pqr"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` returns an array that includes numeric keys AND named field keys. So each column value is returned twice. So you'll end up with rows like...

```
[0] => 123
['id'] => 123
[1] => 'Bobby'
['name'] => 'Bobby'
[2] => '1994-03-03'
['date_of_birth'] => '1994-03-03'
```

Add the `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` or `SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC` parameter to `sqlsrv_fetch_array` like so:

`$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)`